# What does the bracket [ ] mean when it comes after a class name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

For example,

```
class BasicTransitionFunction(TransitionFunction[GrammarBasedState]):
      ...
```

where `TransitionFunction` is the base class of `BasicTransitionFunction`, and `GrammarBasedState` is also a class name. I only know that `[]` can be used to indexed arrays. What does it mean here?

Comment: It means that `TransitionFunction` is a generic type. For example, `List` is a generic type, so you can have `List[Int]`.

Comment: Building off Sraw's comment/comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics

Comment: @Sraw So is this only for annotation?

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax for generic types. Like @Sraw said, it means that `TransitionFunction` is a generic type. For example, `List` is a generic type, so you can have `List[Int]`.

This is the same idea as for C++ templates (e.g. `std::vector<int>`).

So here `BasicTransitionFunction` is a subclass of a `TransitionFunction` between `GrammarBasedState`s.

Comment: So what's the meaning of doing this? Is it only for annotation? Since Python is a dynamically typed language.

Comment: This is a definition of a class; this has nothing to do with dynamic or static typing.

Comment: I mean for C++ templates std::vector<int>, if you pass a string to the vector there will be an error. But for python, the definition itself will not lead to an error if you pass a str to List[Int].